# Has user 'last seen' information been moved?

Tags: support, user-interface, profile-page

My recollection is that "last seen" information was prominently displayed on a user's profile page right after "member since" on the top line.

As I look at profiles today, it is not there.

I have been able to find it in "network profile" page, "accounts" tab.  The "accounts" tab appears to be the default display when selecting "view network profile" under "communities".  However, some users do not have a "view network profile" link under "communities" - for them, I have to go to "network profile", which opens to a default display of "top" tab and then *select* the "accounts" tab.  This makes it rather more laborious to get to "last seen", which used to be one click away.

I have recently hit 15K rep which has changed some of my displays, but I think this is unrelated.

Can someone confirm that this change was made recently?
Was a purpose stated for the change?

Comment: Over on Stack Apps, someone has provided a [LegacyProfiles userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/9074/legacyprofiles-bringing-back-the-old-profile-stats) that brings back the 'last seen' stat.

Answer (score 5):

### This was a recent privacy related change

[Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)

The work was done while they were making the profile more 'responsive', but was motivated by [privacy concerns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368289#comment1228272_368289)

> We've actually had quite a few complaints in the past that a "Last seen" indicator public visible is a creepy and intrusive thing to have on a user profile. So I imagine the disappointment will be very 50/50 here. ;) – [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) Aug 5 at 22:42

Comment: Thank you.  Strange that "privacy concerns" have made the information less accessible but still available; that is, making it more difficult for legitimate users but not removing it from the ability to be used maliciously.

Comment: @Kirt How would one use that information maliciously?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov AncientSwordRages's link is to the post includes discussion of privacy concerns.  Some posts that specifically raise such concerns are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368346), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61241/please-make-the-last-seen-entry-optional) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23148/last-seen-time-appears-on-google-and-se-profile-pages-and-should-be-removed)